# swift core data fetching relationship

Tags: core-data, swift, ios8, relationship, xcode6gm

I'm a little bit confused try to fetch relation data from coredata in swift

**Person Entity**
contains the name of person and Unique Id. The relation with Books is ONE to Many

For example

```
Person Entity: 
idPerson = 25 - namePerson = John
idPerson = 26 - namePerson = Steve
```

**Books Entity** contains the title of books, Unique Id for the book and a relation ID with person (personBook). The relation with Person is ONE to ONE
For example

```
Books Entity: 
idBook = 2543 - titleBook = title one - personBook = 25
idBook = 2544 - titleBook = title two - personBook = 25
idBook = 2545 - titleBook = title three - personBook = 26
```

here my data model screenshot: (no image because i have no reputation)

Person class

```
        @objc(Person)
        class Person: NSManagedObject {
              @NSManaged var idPerson: String
              @NSManaged var namePerson: String
              @NSManaged var booksRel: NSSet

        }
```

Books class

```
        @objc(Books)
        class Books: NSManagedObject {
              @NSManaged var bookTitle: String
              @NSManaged var idBook: String
              @NSManaged var personBook: String
              @NSManaged var personRel: Person

        }
```

Fetch code

```
    let appDel:AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
    let context:NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!

    let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Books")
    request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false

    request.fetchLimit = 30

    ////////////////////////////
    // CODE TO JOIN Person entity WHERE personBook = idPerson
    ////////////////////////////

    var results:NSArray = context.executeFetchRequest(request, error: nil)!

    for temp in results {
         var data = temp as Books
         ///////////////////////////////////////
         //println(data.namePerson) ----> not working
         ///////////////////////////////////////
    }
```

is possibile to fetch for every book the related namePerson based on namePerson = personBook ?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 13):

You don't need a property `personBook` for your `Books` entity.

Let's create a `Person` managedObject (using Swift 1.0):

```
let person = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Person", inManagedObjectContext: context) as Person
person.idPerson = 23
person.namePerson = "John"

var error: NSError?
if !context.save(&error) {
    println("Unresolved error \(error), \(error!.userInfo)")
    abort()
}
```

When you create a `Books` managedObject, you can link it to `person` like this:

```
let book = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Books", inManagedObjectContext: context) as Books
book.bookTitle = "My book Title"
book.idBook = 2547
book.personRel = person

var error: NSError?
if !context.save(&error) {
    println("Unresolved error \(error), \(error!.userInfo)")
    abort()
}
```

Now, when you want to make a fetch on `Books`, you can do like this:

```
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Books")
var error: NSError?
var booksArray = context.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error:&error)
if let error = error {
    println("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    abort()
}

for book in booksArray as [Books] {
    let person = book.personRel as Person

    println(person.namePerson)
    println(person.idPerson)
}
```

Comment: thanks @POB , but the coredata are saved from a json and then fetched by the application. For example today you receveid only 1 new person and 50 books.

Comment: I try to explain better. The app have the two entity update in different time from a json. My main question is .... When i fetch the Books entity for example in a table view or in a collection view can i join the Books entit with person entity for idPerson=personBook to retrive the bookTitle and the associated namePerson. Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 2):

If I have understood your question / data structure correctly, you will want to do something like:

```
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Books")
let bookPersonPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "personRel.idPerson == %@", person.idPerson)
fetchRequest.predicate = bookPersonPredicate
```